# How to get data from mysql database based on date ?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Mysql table called `clients`where one filed called `conn_date` is containing clients registered date.

Now I want to get data from this table where `conn_date` is greater than registered date and less than current date.

For e.g. If user registered on `2016-06-01` then all data should be return where `coon_date` is greater than `2016-06-01` and less than **Current Date**

**conn_date column value**

```
2016-06-01
2016-08-30
2016-08-30
2016-07-01
2016-08-03
2016-09-18
```

**Mysql Query**

```
$get_client = "SELECT SUM(cbp.pay_amount) AS total_pay_amount, SUM(cbp.discount_amount) AS total_discount_amount, SUM(cbp.advance_amount) AS total_advance_amount, SUM(cbp.due_amount) AS total_due_amount, cbp.advance_amount, cbp.bill_month, YEAR(cbp.bill_month) AS myBillYear, MONTH(cbp.bill_month) AS myBillMonth, cbp.cbp_id, cbp.due_amount, cbp.pay_amount, c.conn_date, c.status, c.client_id, c.monthly_bill, c.user_id, c.address, c.contact_no, zone.zone_name, package.package_name, c.bill_date FROM clients AS c 
LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.zone_id = c.zone_id 
LEFT JOIN package ON package.package_id = c.package_id 
LEFT JOIN clients_pay_bill AS cbp ON cbp.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE c.uid = '$uid' AND c.conn_date <= CURDATE() ";

if($selected_zone != "all") {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id != '' ";
} elseif($selected_zone == "all") {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id != '' ";
} else {
    $get_client .= " AND c.zone_id = '$selected_zone' ";
}

$get_client .= " GROUP BY c.client_id ORDER BY c.client_id DESC ";
```

Now it's showing only current month data not greater than registered date !

Comment: I don't see any reference to a registration date in your query.

Comment: registration date is `conn_date` column

Comment: *Now I want to get data from this table where `conn_date` is greater than registered date*. How can `conn_date` be greater than itself?

Comment: Yes that's my question. May be I did wrong when creating column. Should I create another column to compare data which is greater than register date and less than current date ?

Comment: The question makes no sense to me, sorry.

Comment: @shmosel 
 
Basically I have 2 html drop down field where one is for year and one is for date. Now I can select any year and date from these html drop down menu and I want the data should be return where date is greater than conn_date value and less than current date

Comment: You mean where `conn_date` is between the selected date and the current date?

Comment: Yes exactly but if I select 2015 as year and 02 as month but user registered on 2016 and 02 then date should not be return.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're leaving out a critical piece of information but I don't know what it is because you're leaving it out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try using below query:

it will return data records between `2016-06-01` and `current date`.

```
select * from clients where conn_date < CURDATE() and conn_date > '2016-06-01'
```

Comment: `2016-06-01` this date is already entered to db. I Just used here to testing purpose. So how can get date from registered date and less than current date ?

Comment: you have mentioned in the question that you want data between dates, and the query above will do the same,  if there is anything else then  explain.

Comment: Basically I have 2 html drop down field where one is for year and one is for date. Now I can select any year and date from these html drop down menu and I want the data should be return where date is greater than `conn_date` value and less than current date.